# Calculation of Matrix

Tags: matrices

I would like to know how to calculate this.
For example, in row, it shows size (SS,S,M and L) and in column, it shows colour (red, blue, yellow). If i calculate the number of units in each size and color, how to calculate this? looks like the size is 3, 4. Anyway for me to calculate this:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 5 & 8 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 7 & 5\\
2 & 5 & 8 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: check what happens if you multiply this matrix by vector with all ones components.

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: you mean for example, 2581 x 212 or something like that?

Comment: I mean [matrix-vector multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Linear_maps). If you are not familiar with linear algebra, what kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: Yes i know that is linear algebra but when i tried to calculate it, i just thought the size is different in row and column so just wonder if i could calculate it. I am just a beginner of this calculation

Comment: for example if I calculate ss size in red, the calculation should be 212 and 2581 (row and column) if i am correct.....but the size is different so as far as i understand, i cannot calculate this that way that I guess now

Comment: Let $A$ be your matrix. Let $x = [1, 1, 1, 1]^T$. What type of object is $Ax$? Can you find it?

Comment: i guess iti s transpose?